# Find all matches of two-character string in a text file and swap them

Tags: regex, string, shell

Searching through a text file for an underscore preceded by a punctuation mark --- `[.?!;:]_` --- I wish to reverse their order.

For example, given the line

`On this _line,_ I show an example. !_`

I wish to change it to:

`On this _line_, I show an example. _!`

I can find all cases with, say Silver Searcher or ripgrep:

`rg '[.?!;:]_' myfile.txt`

but am unsure about how the two characters are then swapped and written in-place or to a new file.

I could just use `sed` for each punctuation instance, for example:

`sed -ie 's/,_/_,/g' myfile.txt`

then

`sed -ie 's/\._/_\./g' myfile.txt`

then...

but it would be nice to perform this with one command.

Can I refer to the found instance and use it in ripgrep's `-r ARG` option?
Or am I barking up the wrong tree and wise to use another *tool?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`sed` supports backreferences to capture groups** defined in the regex argument of `s` calls in the replacement argument (using `bash` here-string syntax (`<<<`) for brevity):

```
$ sed -E 's/([.?!;:])_/_\1/g' <<<'On this _line,_ I show an example. !_'
On this _line,_ I show an example. _!
```

`\1` refers to the 1st capture group (`(...)`) in the regex.

Note that `-E` was used to enable support for *extended* regexes, which use modern syntax - both GNU `sed` and BSD/macOS `sed` support this option.

---

Generally, you don't need `sed`'s `-e` option, unless you're passing the `sed` script in *multiple parts*, in which case each part must be `-e`-prefixed.

As for ***in-place* updating of the input file:**

`-ie` probably does *not* do (exactly) what you want: while it does update the input file (by replacing it with a new file with updated content), it creates a *backup file with suffix `e`*, because `e` is interpreted as option `-i`'s *option-argument*.

If the intent is *not* to create a backup file, the syntax - sadly - differs based on what `sed` implementation you're using:

- GNU `sed`: `sed -i ...`

  - `-i` must *not* be directly followed by any other options / characters.
- BSD/macOS `sed`: `sed -i '' ...`

  - `-i` *must* be followed by `''` as the *next, separate* argument.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. I couldn't use the `-i` in-place option so just used sed ....... oldfile.txt > newfile.txt

Comment: @ChrisHanning: Glad to hear it; please see my update re `-i`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way you can do it with a single line:

```
sed  's/\([^\w\s]\)\(_\)/\2\1/g' test.txt
```

Essentially, you are looking for two characters, and swapping them.

s/  - This starts the substitution

`\(    \)`  - This escapes the parentheses. Gotta do this, even if its ugly.

`\s` a whitespace character

`[ ]` sets up a character class

`^` negates at the first position inside a character class

`[^\w\s]` all characters that are not letters or whitespace (aka punctuation)

Then we get to the next match, an underscore. We make this the second item to check for

`\(_\)` - First, find punctuation and mark that as match number 1, then find an underscore, right next to it, and mark it as match number 2.

`/\2\1/` - Now, swap matches 1 and 2

`/g` - do this globally.

The end. Now, you can output this to another file, or use another `sed` modifier, (the `-i` switch), to change the file inline.

Comment: This works well also, with one small caveat: I can't pick up `-` characters as they are a special case, so unfortunately ^\w as a catch-all doesn't work in my particular case. For the general case this is also worth noting.

Comment: Since `_` is non-variable, this would be simpler: `sed  's/\([^\w\s]\)_/_\1/g' test.txt`