# How to replace characters in sed with other characters

Tags: sed, character

Here 's the output I am getting.

```
"last_name:""abcd","email:""abc.com","first_name:""xyz"
```

Desired output is:

```
"last_name":"abcd","email":"abc.com","first_name":"xyz"
```

Comment: Is it JSON ? It really looks like inner JSON. Have you tried anything ?

Comment: I am trying to convert it to JSON format.

Comment: Where the string is coming from ?

Comment: If one of the characters is *not* fixed, see also:  [Find all matches of two-character string in a text file and swap them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43433255/find-all-matches-of-two-character-string-in-a-text-file-and-swap-them).

Answer (score 0):

This simple `sed` may help you on same:

```
sed 's/:""/":"/g'   Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** `sed` works on method of substituting source`:""`(in this case) with target(or new string/values)`":"`(in this case). `g` option makes sure that substitution is happening globally in the line.

***Solution 2nd:*** Adding `awk` solution too now:

```
awk '{gsub(/:\042\042/,"\042:\042")} 1'  Input_file
```

***NOTE:*** In case you want to save output in Input_file itself then use `sed -i` in above code in spite of `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `s`*ubstitute* command:

```
echo '"last_name:""abcd","email:""abc.com","first_name:""xyz"' | 
sed 's/:""/":"/g'
```

Output:

```
"last_name":"abcd","email":"abc.com","first_name":"xyz"
```